# Why does the cockpit have windows, is it a structural design burden?

Tags: aircraft-design

Instead of cockpit windows could they have just screens displaying what is happening using a camera? Is it for any useful purpose? Is it a structural burden or is it there for psychological purposes?

Comment: Why do cars have windshields? Why do glasses have lenses? You could replace both with video screens.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. The suggested dupe asks is it possible, the answer to which is simply yes. This asks why is it not done, which has many reasons, some of which are provided in the suggested dupes answers but that doesn't make the question a dupe IMO.

Comment: @Notts90 A dupe is the same question, or, an existing question which yields the same answers.  The linked duplicate does address "why not".

Comment: @Simon there is information in those answers that gives some of the reasons that would answer this question but I think there are benefits to having more specific questions like this one to get better/more specific answers. Yes there is overlap but it's not exactly the same.

Comment: Screens are 2D. The human eye is an exceptional organizational designed to work best in the real 3D world. The information provided to the brain through the eye far exceeds that available from any display system; there will never be a replacement for that.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, it may be better. But what happens if the camera gets dirt (as everything else does in a flight) or if the camera fails for whatever reason? If the aircraft suffered an electrical malfunction and the camera was to turn off? Also, this is way more expensive than just fitting the window. The technology would also increase the weight of the aircraft. It's a good idea that I am sure that aircraft manufacturers have contemplated. It is just too impractical.

Comment: "*this is way more expensive than just fitting the window*": Can you explain why? I'd have thought a camera and a display are less expensive than the windshield anti-ice system alone.